# How to get a return value from an input form?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

```html
<form>
        <input type="number" placeholder="rows" min="1" max="300" id ="RowInput" value="" oninput="rowValue()">
        <p>x</p>
        <input type="number" placeholder="columns" min="1" max="300" id="ColumnInput" value="" oninput="columnValue()"> 
        <input type="submit" id="Submit" value="" onsubmit="getGridValue()" >

      </form>
```

```js
let tile = document.getElementById("tile")
let rowInput = ''
let columnInput = ''
let gridLength = ''


function rowValue() {
    rowInput = document.getElementById('RowInput').value
}

function columnValue() {
    columnInput = document.getElementById('ColumnInput').value 

}

function getGridLength() {
    gridLength = columnInput * rowInput
}

alert(gridLength)
```

So what I'm trying to do is update the gridLength by getting the values from columnInput and rowInput and using them to get a number. I used the oninput eventlisteners to do that, although Im not sure if it's actually returning the user input as a number. And then when used to multiply them both doesn't affect the gridLength variable at all.  I don't understand what Im doing wrong, since the idea of this seems so simple.

Comment: Put the alert inside `getGridLength()`. When it is outside it is called immediately on page load, thus it never works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I believe that caused you problems is the onSubmit. It should appear inside the form element and not inside the input type="submit" element. Either way, I've made some modifications and tested, and the following works just as you wanted:

```
<form onsubmit="getGridLength();">
    <input type="number" placeholder="rows" min="1" max="300" id ="RowInput" value="" oninput="rowValue();">
    <p>x</p>
    <input type="number" placeholder="columns" min="1" max="300" id="ColumnInput" value="" oninput="columnValue();"> 
    <input type="submit" id="Submit" value="">
</form>
<script>
var tile = document.getElementById("tile");
var rowInput;
var columnInput;
var gridLength;

function rowValue() {
    rowInput = document.getElementById('RowInput').value;
}

function columnValue() {
    columnInput = document.getElementById('ColumnInput').value;
}

function getGridLength() {
    gridLength = columnInput * rowInput
    alert(gridLength);
}
</script>
```

Other then that, I would suggest to end each Javascript command with the comma seperator (;) just like I did in the code above. It will be easier for you also on the next programming languages you will be working with, since most of them requires it at the end of a command.

Comment: ahh so mostly just a syntax issue, gotcha! Thank you! This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try code like below:

```
function rowValue() {
    rowInput = document.getElementById('RowInput').value;
    getGridLength();
}

function columnValue() {
    columnInput = document.getElementById('ColumnInput').value;
    getGridLength();
}

function getGridLength() {
    gridLength = columnInput * rowInput;
    console.log(gridLength);
}
```

You can change console.log to alert if needed, though console.log is better.